# How to use authenticate web sockets using node, ws and passport with JWT?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, jwt, passport.js

I have a web server written in **node/express** which uses **passport** to authenticate users with JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

For regular HTTP methods this is what I use:

```
app.get('/api/stuff', isLoggedIn(), (req, res) => {
    //get stuff
    res.send( whatever );
});
```

Where `isLoggedIn` is this function:

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    return passport.authenticate('local-jwt', { session: false });
}
```

The authentication itself is handled by the `'local-jwt'` configuration in passport using a `JWTStrategy` object and it works as expected.

Now I need to add web sockets to this app. I'm using the **ws** library. Here is what I have so far:

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 8080,
    verifyClient: async (info, done) => {
        // ???
        done( result );
    }
});

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    // web socket events
});
```

How do I use the passport authentication to only allow clients with the correct token to connect to the web socket server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `sign` the token with the user's id or anything you are using to differentiate users

```
var today = new Date();
var exp = new Date(today);
exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);
jwt.sign({
        id: user._id,
        exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
    }, secret);
```

then pass the token to the frontend and use it to initialize your Websocket connection with it appended to the url then take and decode it in the server like this

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  verifyClient: async (info, done) => {
    console.log(info.req.url);
    console.log('------verify client------');

    const token = info.req.url.split('/')[1];
    var decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret);

    info.req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).exec();

    /*info.req.user is either null or the user and you can destroy the connection
     if its null */

    done(info.req);
  },
  server
});
```

This is one of many ways. There is a way with sessions but I see you don't want to use them. Also I don't know if you use mongo but it's the same for any database you just have to change some code.

Answer (score 1):

Just extending on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017188/19996289) of C.Gochev with some considerations for people landing on this:

1. Use of `verifyClient` is discouraged in favor of handling client authentication in the 'upgrade' event of the HTTP server. Refer to the [docs](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback) and [#377](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/377#issuecomment-462152231) for more information.
2. It's a better security practice to use cookies over sending the auth token (or any sensitive information) as a URL param/query to mitigate the risk of having it exposed through browser history, referer header, network monitoring/logging tools, etc. [Here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/express-session-parse/index.js) is an example from `ws` that makes use of session cookies (abstracted away with `express-session`).

Comment: Hi and welcome! To make SO a self contained platform, we always try to include facts directly in the answers, not just provide links. Links are using to provide more detailed information, but the basics should be included in the answer itself. WHY is it bad to include sensitive info in query params (caches and forensic logs for example)