# Intercept websocket request to get handshake data before proxying it to server via http-proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-proxy

Here is my code for proxying the websocket request to the targer server. I'm using `http-proxy` module in nodejs to proxy my request https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy What I want to achieve is that like in case of REST requests in http-proxy, we use `proxyReq` event to modify the request if we want by accessing headers and `req.body`, I want to do the same for weboscket request as I want to access the auth middleware data that is passed from the socket client. I don't want to log or intercept the traffic sent or received after the weboscket connection, instead I want to intercept (not modify) the actual request that contains auth middleware data on `proxyReqws` event. Any help & guidance would be appreciated.

```
var app = express();
const fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const credentials = { key: fs.readFileSync("localhost.key"), cert: fs.readFileSync("localhost.cert") };

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ ws: true });
var server = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(8080)

proxy.on('proxyReqWs', (proxyReq, req, socket, options, head) => {
    //before the request is actually proxyed to the target server
    //access websocket request here
});

app.use('/socket.io', function (req, res) {
    proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
     //on response, do something
    });
    proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
        console.log(err)
    })
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: { host: address.host, port: address.port, path: '/socket.io' } })

})

server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    console.log("Upgraded to websockets")
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head, { target: { host: address.host, port: address.port, path: '/socket.io' } });
});
```

Comment: (1) WebSocket is a very low level protocol. It doesn't really have the notion of requests and responses, it is more similar to raw TCP than HTTP. Unless some other protocol is built on top of it. Or are you talking about WebSocket handshake? (2) we don't know how your particular case works, what kind of auth mechanism you use. There's no way for us to help you. (3) It is impossible to put a proxy between client and server and not to maintain two connections. Unless, again, the custom protocol allows "virtual connections" on top of a single websocket connection.

Comment: do u wanna authenticate the user |


 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010623/how-to-use-authenticate-web-sockets-using-node-ws-and-passport-with-jwt

Comment: I have edited the question. I dont want  to authenticate the client, but want to access auth middleware data